# Spring boot - Validate data in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I need to perform a manual validation of DTO inside a service of my Spring Boot application. In case of validation error is it better to throw a custom exception or a ConstraintViolationException?

In the case of a ConstraintViolationException, how can I throw it?

Comment: Are you using JSR303 and perhaps annotations elsewhere?

Comment: use Valid and Validated annotations and don't forget to import javax.validation dependency as you need to use provided annotations on your DTO.

Comment: Yes, in other part of my project I've used javax annotation, but in this case i need to execute a manual validation (with a simple if) of my DTO in the service. I need to check the unique constraint and another constraint

Comment: Like some database uniquenes or so?

Comment: Yes, I check the unique constraint in service in order to return a better message than sql exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick to using validation annotations and ConstraintViolationException to keep the code and validation as simple as possible.

There are many options depending on how you are planning to make the validation but I use - in similar cases - an approach where I create an annotation and a validator that are used just as any validation annotation in controller, for example.

Validation stuff looks something like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidatorAnnotation.MyValidator.class)
public @interface MyValidatorAnnotation {
    String message() default "not a valid DTO";
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    // I have created this validator as interface's inner class to
    // to keep code simpler but it can be "outer" class also.
    @Component // this is not necessarily needed
    class MyValidator
            implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidatorAnnotation, MyDto> {
        @Resource
        private MyRepository myRepository;
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(MyDto myDto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            boolean valid = true;
            // If you need some custom messages, try something like:
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(myDto.getName())) {
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("NAME WAS BLANK")
                        .addPropertyNode("name")
                        .addConstraintViolation();
                valid = false;
            }
            // Any checks you need to do with myRepository
            // or with any other resources
            return valid;
        }
    }
}
```

Then using/triggering this validation depends on few things. See below example of the service what should be considered:

```
@Service
@Validated
public class MyService {
    // In this method validation will not work if called from MyService itself.
    // Works only when called from "outside" so from any other managed bean
    public void handleMyDtoExt(@Valid MyDto myDto) {
        // furious handling
    }
    // Works when called anywhere even from service itself.
    // The drawback is that you need more code & injection & testing which you of
    // course want to avoid.
    // In this case you also might not want add @Validated to your service.
    @Resource
    private Validator validator;
    private void handleMyDto(MyDto myDto) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyDto>> cvs = validator.validate(myDto);
        if(!cvs.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(cvs);
        }
        // furious handling
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to send another information to the validator? For example the entity or the ID?

Comment: @Mark116 yes but I am not sure if is the best practice. Might be good alternative but hard to know without having any details about your validation. You could for example create a simple wrapper class that holds any data that is needed to make validation - like dto & entity -in its fields and then make validator to validate that wrapper class. In that way you might not need to inject anything to the validator itself.

Comment: It's possibile mock custom validator in jUnit test?

Comment: It is possible and it is possible also to test the validator with mock stuff. Maybe you could make another question where you have some minimal code you have tried to explain a bit more in details what and how you are testing? It would help answering.